# How to apply some sort of matrix transformation over an entire grid?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

(this isn't homework - just want to learn)

let's say I started with a single point, and this grid's dimensions are arbitrary for the example, where 1 is a point.

first frame:

```
0000000
0000000
0001000
0000000
0000000
```

next frame:

```
0000000
0001000
0010100
0001000
0000000
```

next frame:

```
0001000
0010100
0100010
0010100
0001000
```

and so on... where a circle of 1s grows outward, and the radius grows larger, but the circle itself remains continuously connected around the edge. Also the original point doesn't have to be in the center, but the circle should grow to each edge it can regardless.

I'm researching how to do this and getting stuck. I'm interested in how to do this the right way with linear algebra and matrix math, but if the explanation can be as friendly as possible please :)

Only focused on 2d for this example not to over complicate it :)

ty, any help appreciated!!

Comment: In 2d if frame 0 has a 1 at (0,0) then at frame n there will be 1's at all positions (x,y) satisfying the equation $|x|+|y|=n,$ where |x| and |y| refer to the absolute values of the coordinates, i.e. drop any minus signs. [of course at frame n there will be 0's at all points (x,y) which do *not* satisfy the equation. Also for this description one needs to start the indexing of frames at 0 instead of the usual 1, so first frame is frame 0, second frame is frame 1 and so on]

Comment: Interesting! Although I love this example, is this possible with matrix math of some sort?

Comment: Matrix math does not work on an infinite board, and your diamond shapes need more and more of the xy plane as the index of frame increases. The only thing that *might* work would be to have the matrix involved be of increasing dimension as the frame index increases. [e.g. for your third frame would need at least a 5X5 matrix, and so on.]

Comment: I've heard of matrix math used to scale an image, isn't it possible, since the image can be of any size?

Comment: To do this via matrices would require that one works, not with only points with both coordinates integers, but instead allow both points to be any real numbers. Then one would begin with the real version of your second frame, i.e. the set A of pairs (x,y) satisfying $|x|+|y|=1.$ Note A is an infinite set of points. [No way around since your second frame is just 4 points and multiplying by a matrix would always give 4 points.] OK now for each point (x,y) in A we write it as a column vector size 2 by 1 top entry x bottom entry y. [continued next]

Comment: This is multiplied by the matrix which is n times the identity matrix to obtain level n. I don't see much advantage in introducing the matrices like this, however. Just book-keeping.